# How do I access Dart variables from Chrome DevTools?

Tags: dart, google-chrome-devtools

How do I access Dart variables from Chrome DevTools?
The Dart Library is located in $, were I can find several instances of main $.main, however, none of them include the variable set.

```
void main() {
  var test = "Hi there";
}
```

None of $.main* has $.main.test. How do I access it?

Answer (score 0):

You need Dartium to access Dart values.  Chrome DevTools stand alone won't do that.

Comment: Dartium is so buggy, ie canvas drawings are just flickering, so I have to use Chrome. As everything is compiled to js, it has to be available somewhere in the devtools, since the variables are actually there and running.

Comment: Agreed, but that's the cost of using Dart, like most things Google it's (in beta) and never finished.